# X11 Tkinter + PIL + py2app = IOError cannot identify image file

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, py2app, ioerror

I have a problem with a python program (python 2.7.3, X11 Tkinter, py2app 0.6.4, MacOS X 10.7.4) that I'm trying to export to py2app.  The problem only started occurring in the standalone py2app-ified app version of the program.  When I run the python source file from which the app was created, **the problem does not exist**, so I feel it must have something to do with the py2app export.

The problem:  When I start the GUI, the first time I try to load a valid image file, the image fails to load, and I get the following error from the PIL Image module:

```
File "Image.pyc", line 1980, in open
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

When I then (without closing the GUI or anything) try to open **the exact same file**, it loads perfectly, no errors or problems.  This happens every time, with any image file I try - the first attempt to load fails, subsequent attempts succeed.  I should add that after that first error, **no image files ever fail to load** - even if they are different from the first one.

A few notes:
 - The image file is a sequence, and is very large (around 300 MB), so to speed up the loading process, I use a mmap.  I have tried removing the mmap step, and handing a regular file object directly to ImagePIL.open it directly, and the problem is unaffected.
 - I also tried seeking to the beginning of the file before giving it to ImagePIL.open, but that had no effect. 
 - The py2app setup file is pretty vanilla - it just includes a few config files and an icon.

Here is the relevant part of the offending image load function:

```
import Image as ImagePIL
import mmap as m
...
...
def loadImage(self):
    errorLog.debug("Attempting to open image \""+self.filenameVar.get()+"\"")
    try:
        if self.fileMap is not None:
            self.fileMap.close()
        imageFile = open(self.filenameVar.get(), 'r')
        self.fileMap = m.mmap(imageFile.fileno(), 0, prot=m.PROT_READ)
#       self.fileMap.seek(0)
        self.imageSeries = ImagePIL.open(self.fileMap)
        imageFile.close()
    except(IOError):
        errorLog.exception("Failed to open image \""+self.filenameVar.get()+"\"")
        return
```

I'm pretty stumped - any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Edit:  I should add that Tkinter, PIL, and py2app were installed using MacPorts 2.1.2, in the off chance that helps.

Comment: Are you really using Tkinter with X11 under OSX ? Does it work after you run `python setup.py py2app -A` (note the `-A`) ?

Comment: @mmgp:  I just tried building my program with py2app in alias mode, and the problem does not occur!!!  It works perfectly.  Why on earth would that be?  **Do you have any idea how I can get this to work in deployment mode**?  Thanks!!

Oh, and yes, I am really using Tkinter X11 on OSX.  I recently found out that there is a Tkinter version that uses native windowing in OSX, and am planning to switch to that, but haven't yet.

Comment: I could guess that the other libraries required for loading a specific image format are not being included/found. I believe you can still load a bmp image, but a png one would fail if the guess is correct. I've seen people reporting problems when combining PIL and py2app, search for it.

Comment: @mmgp: I'll try, although literally the same image file will fail to load the first time, then succeed the next, so I don't see how it could be a library inclusion issue.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I didn't see that, so you can ignore that part of the comment.

Comment: The fact that you're using a `mmap` instead of a real file or string may have something to do with the problem -- so I would suggest trying it without it and see if the same thing happens. FWIW, in the v1.1.7 source code I have, I see things that indicate it might behave differently on a second attempt -- unfortunately I don't understand it well enough at this point to say more.

Comment: @martineau:  thanks, I thought that might be it too, so I tried it without the mmap business, and the problem was still there - thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that py2app does not include PIL's image plugins into the application bundle even though one of the py2app recipes tries to ensure that they are included.

One thing you could try is to build with "python setup.py py2app --packages=PIL" and then use "import PIL.Image as ImagePIL" to use it.

I don't understand yet why the PIL recipe doesn't work, it might be something in the way MacPorts builds python packages (I don't use MacPorts myself).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - unfortunately, that didn't fix the problem.  Still stumped by this one!  Love to have more answers - anyone out there have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the result of inconsistency between Pillow version 3.0.0 and py2app.

I suggest two solution to avoid PIL (Pillow)

1. Use opencv instead of PIL.
2. uninstall the current version of Pillow and install a previous one like 1.7.8